# Vagrant up SSL issue

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

We run vagrant through Homestead on our production server. When initializing vagrant, I get the following error when the copying starts of our production (non self signed) certificates:

```
    homestead-7: --- Copying *domain* SSL crt and key ---
    homestead-7: cp: cannot stat '/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/*domain*.cert.combined': No such file or directory
    homestead-7: cp: cannot stat '/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/*domain*.key': No such file or directory
    homestead-7: cp: cannot stat '/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/*domain*.cacert': No such file or directory
    homestead-7: --- Turning SSL on in nginx.conf. ---
```

Path to the keys are correct. I also copied them to a different folder with different user permissions... Makes no difference.

We need the SSL certificates to work on the VM or else we can't talk to our API.

What are we doing wrong here? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, finally, finally...

In `Homestead.yaml`

you have to make sure you have the correct map route setup:

```
folders:

    - map: /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains
      to: /home/vagrant/domains
```

in `after.sh`

you again have to mention the correct scripts folder:

```
# Save our Homestead.yaml mapped folder to a var.
scripts_dir="/home/vagrant/domains"
#scripts_dir="/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/"
```

I used this one  `#scripts_dir="/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/"` before, but that doesn't work. I can only be the mapped folder.